# How can I make a <div> expand to enclose a large number of <li> elements within a <ul>?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="columns">
   <ul class="controls-buttons">
       <li><a data-href="/xx" id="btn-1" Topic 50.5">1</a></li>
       ...
       <li><a data-href="/yy" id="btn-2" Topic 50.5">2</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul.controls-buttons {
   float: right;
}

li {
   height: 1.8em !important;
   margin-left: 0.7em !important;
   padding: 0.333em 0.29em !important;
}

ul.controls-buttons li {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   margin: -1px 0 -1px 0.5em;
   line-height: 1.333em;
   padding: 0.333em 0.25em;
}
```

There are approximately 100 buttons and they flow outside the boundaries of the enclosing `<div class="columns"`

Is there a way that I can make the `<ul>` occupy space so the `<div>` expands to enclose it ?

Comment: It's because you use float, you need to use "clear"

Comment: Yes but the buttons themselves display perfectly. It's just they are not enclosed.

Comment: overflow:hidden; in your div

Comment: add overflow:auto to the div and don't float your ul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `<div class="columns" style="overflow: hidden;">` then it will occupy the same space as the float inside of it.

Answer (score 2):

i think `overflow:hidden;` in your `div.column` will solve your probem

for more knowledge :: [SOURCE](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html)

> **overflow: hidden;** This value indicates that the content is clipped and that no scrolling
>   user interface should be provided to view the content outside the
>   clipping region.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't, you should float the div.
If you float something in the inner of a div but not the div itself, this can cause problems with overlapping. In your case that the  list is higher than the div

Comment: So can you tell me what CSS I could use. I am just not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: Add this to your CSS:
.columns{
  float:left;
}

Answer (score 0):

This CSS works:

```
    ul.controls-buttons {
    float: right;
    }

li {
   height: 1.8em !important;
   margin-left: 0.7em !important;
   padding: 0.333em 0.29em !important;
}

ul.controls-buttons li {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   margin: -1px 0 -1px 0.5em;
   line-height: 1.333em;
   padding: 0.333em 0.25em;
   width:100%
}
```